# PL/SQL Error bad bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

Where is the problem with my code. It should work, but Compiler says:

```
Error(5,14): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAZWA_GRUPY'
Error(6,1): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAZWA_GRUPY'
Error(6,25): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAZWA_GRUPY'
Error(7,78): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAZWA_GRUPY'
Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

in this:

```
DROP TABLE Grupy CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ;

CREATE TABLE Grupy
  (
    idGrupy NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    nazwa   VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL ,
    opis    VARCHAR2 (150)
  ) ;

ALTER TABLE Grupy ADD CONSTRAINT Grupy_PK PRIMARY KEY
(
  idGrupy
)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER wyzwalacz
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF nazwa ON Grupy
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
stara_nazwa VARCHAR2;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Wstawiono nową nazwę do tabeli Grupy');
stara_nazwa:=:new.nazwa_grupy;
:new.nazwa_grupy:=upper(:new.nazwa_grupy);
dbms_output.put_line('Nazwa grupy '||stara_nazwa||' została zmieniona na '||:new.nazwa_grupy);
END;

Insert into Grupy Values(1, 'Vw AG','Należą do niej marki :Audi, Bentley, Bugatti, Ducati, Lamborghini, Seat, Skoda, Volkswagen, Scania, MAN, Porsche');

select * from Grupy;
```

Comment: Inside trigger body `:NEW` and `:OLD` let you access new and old values of the fields. There is no "nazva_grupy" column in `Grupy` table.

Comment: Ok, thx for help, but now there is only one error:

Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT"

Comment: you need a '/' without quotes on the line before INSERT. Else SQLPLUS doesn't know what to do with your trigger code block. Once you do, it will know that code block should be executed and then it will process INSERT correctly.